# How to display value to next step in multistep form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need help with the following query,

how we can show input field value from the previous step to next step in **multistep forms**

like **Microsoft login** they show email to next step like in image is showing below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

And in the next page use this:

```
document.getElementById("E-mail").innerHTML = input;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I already fix this problem, I fix problem almost similar to that, I ran into a problem because I'm not good at javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy javascript work. You just make the input forms and put ID's on them. When you go to the next step, The Value that was put by user doesn't go away. You can take it with javascript and use it later on next step too.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can get that data in the response from the backend, on in the frontend you can make use of [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to save the value and use it later on the next page.