# Multistep form display data from previous step in text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple step form in html/css/js
I'm really noob with JS so excuse my ignorance.

My form is like :

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/ws/injection.php">
        <div class="content active" id="content1">
            <h3 ><?php echo esc_html($settings['step1_title']); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo esc_html($settings['step1_descr']); ?></p>
            <input type="text" name="zone" class="step1zone" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step1_placeholder']); ?>">
            <input type="button" class="step1next" onclick="nextTab('tab2')" value="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step1_button_text']); ?>" />
        </div>

        <div class="content" id="content2">
            <h3><?php echo esc_html($settings['step2_title']); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo esc_html($settings['step2_descr']); ?></p>
            <input type="button" onclick="nextTab('tab3')" name="delai" value="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step2_option_1']); ?>" />
            <input type="button" onclick="nextTab('tab3')" name="delai" value="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step2_option_2']); ?>" />
            <input type="button" onclick="nextTab('tab3')" name="delai" value="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step2_option_3']); ?>" />
            <input type="button" onclick="nextTab('tab3')" name="delai" value="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step2_option_4']); ?>" />
        </div>

        <div class="content" id="content3">
            <h3><?php echo esc_html($settings['step3_title']); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo  esc_html($settings['step3_descr']); ?></p>
            <input type="text" class="step3data" name="nom" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step3_prenom']); ?>">
            <input type="text" class="step3data" name="prenom" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step3_nom']); ?>"><br />
            <input type="text" class="step3data" name="mail" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step3_email']); ?>">
            <input type="text" class="step3data" name="tel" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html($settings['step3_phone']); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="um4b4cH5bSnA2WnQ7K98" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr($settings['step3_button_text']); ?>" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

and I have simple JS to manage next steps :

```
function nextTab(tabId) {
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
    const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
    const activeTab = document.querySelector('.tab.active');
    const activeContent = document.querySelector('.content.active');

    const nextTab = document.getElementById(tabId);
    const nextContent = document.getElementById(`content${tabId.slice(-1)}`);

    activeTab.classList.remove('active');
    if (activeTab !== nextTab) {
        activeTab.classList.add('valid');
    }
    activeContent.classList.remove('active');
    nextTab.classList.add('active');
    nextContent.classList.add('active');

}
```

As my post is not sended between steps, I can not use $_POST to get the values.
I suppose there is a way to do in JS, I finded this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63007879/11584403
But I'm not able to make it works on my form.
I wish on step 3 to write something like "get results for xxx ( correspond to my input name "zone" from step 1 ).

Any advice would be apreciate.

Comment: Aside: You can use `<?=` in place of `<?php echo` inside your form.

Comment: Would this answer help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919281/322084

Comment: I don't think so ? I'm really bad with JS so I maybee don't understand what it does.